# Java: How do I read and store data from input file?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I need to store data from an input file that has the following form:

```
k=5
1: 62 35
2: 10 49

1 Banana
2 Apple
```

I need to store the value for k as an int, and then I need to store the int values of the next two lines as an [2][2]-array, and finally I need the strings "Banana" and "Apple" to be stored in a list. I tried using the useDelimiter but it ignores my delimiters and reads whole lines as one line instance.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    File file = new File("input.text");

    try {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        scanner.useDelimiter("n=");
        scanner.useDelimiter(".:");             
        int k = scanner.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
                array[i][j] = scanner.nextInt();
            }
        } scanner.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: And the code of your attempt is...

Comment: Sorry, added what I got this far now.

Comment: you can fetch the whole string using `next()` and apply splitting on them using delimiter.

Comment: Please add the output/result you get and the output/result you desire. For example, what are the array contents, given the sample input you already provided, and what do you want them to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the text always have the same structure, then you could do

```
int k = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine().substring("=")[1]);
String currentLine;
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
   currentLine = scanner.nextLine().substring(currentLine.indexOf(" ") + 1)
   for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
       array[i][j] = currentLine.split(" ")[j];
   }
}
```

Then for the Banana and Apple parsing, apply the same logic. Substring until from the index of the first space + 1 character as we don't want to keep it. Then add that string to your list.